# How to check specific object key value is empty or not in nested object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object

I need to determine whether object key value is empty or not in nested object. Below is the nested object. As you can see, in the options object I have multiple object and I have to check if 'value' key is empty for entire object then it should return true.

```
const obj = {
  options: {
    opt1: {
      value: '',
      state: false,
    },
    opt2: {
      value: '',
      state: false,
    },
    opt3: {
      value: '',
      state: false,
    },
  }
}
```

I have tried below approach

```
for (const key in obj) {
  if (obj[key].value !== null && obj[key].value !== '')
    return false;
  return true;
}
```

May be above approach required bit refactor.

Comment: You should be looping over `obj.options`, not `obj`

Comment: then how I will write if condition. I have also try to pass directly options object but it didn't workout for (const key in options) {
      if (options[key].value !== null && options[key].value !== '')
        return false;
      return true;
    }

Comment: The condition is the same. Just change the loop to `for (const key in obj.options)`

Comment: I have tried not working for me

Comment: `return true` should not be inside the loop, it should be after the loop. Your code is only checking the first key.

Answer (score 0):

It might be more readable to use [`every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) on `Object.values(obj.options)`

```js
const obj = {
    options: {
        opt1: { value: '', state: false },
        opt2: { value: '', state: false },
        opt3: { value: '', state: false },
    }
}

const everyOptionHasEmptyValue = Object.values(obj.options).every(o => o.value === '');
console.log(everyOptionHasEmptyValue); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your code:

1. You are actually looping over the whole object which is this `obj` and this is wrong because `obj` has only one "key value pair" which is the options object and so when you loop over the whole `obj` you are NOT checking "values" inside of the options object. Instead what you should do is to loop over the `obj.options` object.
2. Objects are not iterable and you can not loop over them and instead, you should try to convert them to something iterable (like arrays) and then loop over them and you can do this with `Object.entries()` which will pack key value pairs inside of an object inside an array. You can read about it on mdn [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

Before writing the solution, look at the result of this when we use `Object.entries(object)` for an object:

```
const object = {
a: 12,
b: 'hi',
}

console.log(Object.entries(object)) 
// Object.entries(object) = [['a', 12], ['b', 'hi']]
```

So Object.entries basically gives an array of arrays in which that each of the nested arrays contain the key and the related value of it.

So by knowing all of this:

You can achieve what you need like this:

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj.options)) {
 if (value !== null && value !== '') return false;
 else return true;
}
```